How package I use for \dimexpr?
I need to use the command \dimexpr, but in my machine no have an package for it. My specific objective is write this string:
\newcommand{\cancelraizq}\[1]{
    \sbox0{$ \displaystyle \sqrt{\vphantom{#1^{^\cancel{2}}}}$}
    \cancel{\phantom{\usebox0}\hspace{0.5em}}
    \hspace{\dimexpr(-\wd0-0.5em)}
    \sqrt{#1^{\cancel{2}}}}

to generate this expression: 
I have the usual packages for example \usepackage{amsmath}, \usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide},etc, but for \dimexpr I don't know which one to use.

Welcome to TeX.SX! There is now also the \dimeval command, if needed (see the LaTeX user manual, section 5 Expandable floating point (and other) calculations).

It's been built-in to LaTeX since 2017. (And available since the 90s if you're using an eTeX engine)

\dimexpr is a primitive and available always.

By the way, the cancellation is wrong, unless you assume that x is nonnegative.

No time to check now but the backslash before [1] is clearly wrong, remove it. It should be \newcommand{\cancelraizq}[1]{...

I should write {#1^{\cancel{2}}} instead of {#1^{^\cancel{2}}}. My error is this.  I'm sorry for what happened.  Thank you very much for your help.
